# Error after setting different datasources for datagridview combobox cells

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I am trying to display in `DataGridView` control names and fields of database tables. In every row name of a table is displayed in the first cell, and second column allows to choose any of the fields of that table.

To do that, I am handling 'DataGridView.CellBeginEdit' event and fill DataSource for cell with names of the fields. When I am trying to edit those cells, provided list is displayed correctly and can b chose just fine.

However when I try to do the same in another row, I start getting `DataError` events about the cell I have edited.

Event arguments for DataRow have 'Formatting|Display'  in `Context` field, and have the message "Value not allowed in DataGridViewComboBoxCell" (or close to it). In debug, the cell event references has correct `Value` field, but its `DataSource` is null and its `FormattedValue` is empty string. And previously displayed text changes to blank.

How should this be resolved correctly? Should I derive my own custom datagridview cell that displays text but has a combobox editor? If so, how?

Edit: here is code I am currently using:

```
public class FieldDataNeededEventArgs: EventArgs
{
    public List<string> FieldNames
    {
        get; private set;
    }
    public string TableName
    {
        get; private set;
    }
    public ReferenceFieldDataNeededEventArgs(stringdata)
        : base()
    {
        FieldNames = new List<string>();
        TableName= data;
    }
}

...

public event EventHandler<FieldDataNeededEventArgs> FieldDataNeeded =
        new EventHandler<FieldDataNeededEventArgs>((sender, args) => { });

...
    //handler for CellBeginEdit
    //dgvMatch - dataGridView, DocsReferenceToTableMatch is class that datagridview is bound to
    private void dgvMatch_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == dgvMatch.Columns["TableKey"].Index)
        {
            DocsReferenceToTableMatch data = dgvMatch.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as DocsReferenceToTableMatch;
            FieldDataNeededEventArgs ea = new FieldDataNeededEventArgs(data.TableName);
            FieldDataNeeded(this, ea);
            var cell = (dgvMatch.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell);
            cell.DataSource = ea.FieldNames;
        }
    }
    //example handler for the FieldDataNeeded event
    static void ld_ReferenceFieldDataNeeded(object sender, ReferenceFieldDataNeededEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            e.FieldNames.Add(String.Format("{0}_fld{1}", e.ReferenceName, i));
        }
    }
```

Comment: check your dataSource connection state ( open or close state ). put your code for more help.

Comment: my data source isn't connected to database - it is cache filled with data beforehand.
Code added.